# How to access Vuex store in Vue single file component

Tags: vue.js, vuex, quasar-framework

I have a Quasar app running Vue 3 and Vuex 4

During app creation my store is accessible when printed and shows the full object. The store is set in app creation with

```
app.use(store, storeKey)
```

Which produces a fully hydrated object

> {_committing: false, _actions: {…}, _actionSubscribers: Array(0),
> _mutations: {…}, _wrappedGetters: {…}, …}

The vuex state **works perfectly** in my router/index with

```
export default route (function ({ store }) {
  const isLoggedIn = store.state.auth.loggedIn;
```

This example correctly show the loggedIn value I set in my state, so I assume the vuex side must be setup correctly

---

My problem is I haven't been able to find a way to access my state from a Vue component

I tried with useStore() in my setup function

```
setup () {
  const $store = useStore()
  const loggedIn = computed({
    get: () => $store.state.auth.loggedIn,
    set: () => { $store.commit('login') }
  })
```

Which produces a console error that

> injection "store" not found.

and a loggedIn object of

> ComputedRefImpl {dep: undefined, _dirty: true, __v_isRef: true,
> effect: ReactiveEffect, _setter: ƒ, …}

---

I also tried using this.$store in the computed object

```
computed : {
  loggedIn () {
    return this.$store.state.auth.loggedIn
  }
}
```

But I just get the error that

> Property '$store' does not exist on type '{ loggedIn(): any; }'.

---

I assume I must be missing something silly. I just want to call $store.commit('login') or $store.dispatch from the single file component

1. How can I access my Vuex store from the single file .Vue component?

---

Per user10031694 I tried and got a reader working with mapState

```
computed : mapState({
  loggedIn: state => state.auth.loggedIn,
```

Which gets {{loggedIn}} to show the correct field

Comment: Have you tried using vuex `mapState`?

Comment: thanks @user10031694 I got it working that way and updated by answer... still not sure how to call actions though, I'm trying mapActions but haven't got it sorted out yet

Comment: that should be something like `this.$store.dispatch('auth/login')`; that's assuming your path is something like `store/auth.js` and you have an action called `login`